# How to make unique filename when saving Excel worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, save, overwrite, save-as

I have a spreadsheet that is my template that everyone accesses. The first button I want them to hit is my Macro "Save As" button that saves in the correct spot on my SharePoint.

This works great! BUT... it overwrites without warning.

I would like to 1 - make sure it never overwrites - I would prefer it cancel the process without saving over something.

Second, I would prefer that it saves it as "[predetermined name]_copy01" where 01 can go to 99 in case the button gets tapped again by someone else after the sheet is completed by the original person (thus ruining that first person's day).

Here is my current code - how do I at least get a pop up for overwriting, and even better, get the renaming for copies (I am assuming this is some sort of "if" or "if/else" statement)

```
Sub Save_Workook_NewName()

Dim tillDay As Date

If Time < 11 / 24 Then    
    tillDay = Date - 1 + 11 / 24    
Else    
    tillDay = Now    
End If

Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = True

Dim path As String
path = "https://ourcorporatesite.sharepoint.com/sites/tills/Shared%20Documents/Nightly%20Tills/"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=path & Format(Now(), "yy-mm-dd") & "_Tills.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I would swap the date and `"Tills"` and add the time to your date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making a unique file name, I am using the Username of the Excel user and the current time stamp. Thus, it makes sure that every user generates a different file name, always. Just make sure that the code runs more than 1 second (or add the 1 second wait in the name generator):

```
Public Function GenerateName() As String
    GenerateName = Format(Now(), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_MM_ss") & "_" & Environ("Username")
End Function
```

In this case, if you want to save the file it is the following: `2019_11_14_22_08_50_vityata`. As a bonus, it could be easily sorted by date created.

It could be called like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & GenerateName & ".xlsm"
```

Comment: Actually, there is a small flaw in the code above - it may fail during the daylight saving time, when the clocks are reverted with 1 hour, thus the names will not be unique.

Comment: ok so I tried adjusting my path and got error 1004 and have to debug -- here is my updated code

Comment: @AndyLatham - what is the idea of the code in the comment?

Comment: 'Dim path As String
path = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/tills/Shared%20Documents/Nightly%20Tills/"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=path & Format(Now(), "yy-mm-dd") & "_" & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss") & "_Tills.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False'

Comment: "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

Comment: it was! but I just went and added to the original pull for Format(Now(),...) rather than adding a second and it seems to be working now!

Comment: am I just not allowed to call Format(now(),...) twice in a filename?

Comment: @AndyLatham - `format(now)&format(now)` is a legid string, so it should not be a problem.

Comment: ok so it is not liking the colons ":" in the time. I changed them to hyphens and it works and then back to colons and I am getting the same error.

Comment: @AndyLatham - yeah, the columns are not allowed. Why don't you try with my function? Or save the whole path (including the name) to a different variable, print it and examine it.